# simpleXML with special chars in XML-Url

Tags: encoding, utf-8, simplexml

I have a little Problem with my code. I am trying to pull song id's from Spotify.
This works fine for me, but not with special characters in the url (like ü,ö,ä).

I get this warning (first line is the echoed Url):

```
http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=Sportfreunde+Stiller+AND+track:Frühling
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__toString() [simplexmlelement.--tostring]: Node no longer exists in /Applications/AMPPS/www/spotify.php on line 28
```

This is my code:

```
function getID($artist,$title){

$url = utf8_decode("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=".$artist."+AND+track:".$title);
echo $url;
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $id= $xml->track->attributes();
    return($id);

 }

echo getID("Sportfreunde+Stiller","Frühling");
```

How to solve this? I tried utf_encode(), but this didn't work out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with UTF-8 encoding, and certainly not the badly named `utf8_decode`/`utf8_encode` functions, which should really be named `utf8_to_iso8859_1`/`iso8859_1_to_utf8`, and are rarely the right answer to any encoding problem.

URLs can, strictly speaking, only contain a very restricted set of characters - basic letters, numbers, and a few pieces of punctuation. Anything else must be escaped using sequences like `%3f`.

To escape the strings in your URL correctly, you can use the PHP function [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode), e.g.

```
$url = "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=" . urlencode($artist) . "+AND+track:" . urlencode($title);
```